# Unable to boot Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest kernel 5.4

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, dpkg, 20.04

I have recently updated my laptop from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04. During the update process I had some errors that were referring to the kernel. Anyway, once the update was done and I tried to reboot the laptop it got stuck at the boot screen saying:

`not syncing VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown`

So the I rebooted the system, this time selecting the previous kernel (5.3) and Ubuntu 20.04 booted fine. Anyway, when I tried to install the initrams for that kernel I was unable to. It seems that the problem is related to `kernelstub`. The following is from the log of

```
sudo apt reinstall -f linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic apt
reinstall -f linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-kernelstub: line 7: kernelstub:
command not found run-parts:
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-kernelstub exited with return code
127 run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with
return code 1 dpkg: error processing package
linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic (--configure):  installed
linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic package post-installation script
subprocess returned error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while
processing:  initramfs-tools  linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: "*command not found run-parts:*" reinstall the package `debianutils`

Comment: @user535733 that made it even worse. Now my laptop doesn't even start. It gets stuck when it starts: `Failed to execute /usr/lib/systemd/system-generator`. It also says: `Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed`

Comment: Then seems like there is more to the story than we know. Much more than a mere missing package...which in itself was highly suspicious. That simply cannot happen when a properly-working system does a flawless upgrade. You can poke at it, or you can back up your data and reinstall. Without more information about what might have happened to your system before or during the upgrade, there is insufficient information for us to work with.